# MongoDB document count fluctuation

Tags: php, python, mongodb, database

I am facing an issue with the `document` count in a `collection` being slightly erratic.

**Here is my workflow:**

Crawling is first done with `scrapy`. Scraped items are sent through a `pipeline` and prepared for writing to the `collection` using `pymongo` library.

Next, perform a check to see if the item currently exists (using a key) and if so, inherit the `_id` and use `db.collection.save()` to achieve an `upsert`. A check is done to ensure that all `fields` exist before writing.

If the item does not exist, a new `document` is created in the `collection`.

Lastly, a frontend `PHP` webpage allows users to search for `documents` in the `collection` using the `PHP mongoDB driver`.

**Issue**

I started noticing on the webpage that some new documents would appear in one crawl, then disappear from view suddenly, and then mysteriously appear again after the next crawl. So I went into `mongo shell` and found that a specific query would return a fluctuating number of results if sent repeatedly. Something like up by one and then down by two and then back to a stable number.

The thing I don't get is that at no point in the code do I `remove()` any `documents` from the `collection`. My impression is that `db.collection.save()` will only result in an equal or increasing number of documents in the collection.

Is there some form of blocking whereby documents being written cannot be queried? Or does it have something to do with my crawling interval?

**Notes:**

- No indexing is done on the collection
- Each crawl+write process only takes about 5-10s and are repeated in 30s interval.

Code snippet of the query:

```
    $cursor = $collection->find(array( '$or' => array(
            array('post_content' => new MongoRegex("/$safe/i")),
            array('post_user' => new MongoRegex("/^$safe$/i"))
    )));
    $cursor->sort(array('post_datetime' => -1));
```

Comment: Hi, what's the "specific query" that would return the fluctuating number of results ? Interested to see how complex is this query, or are you referring to simple collection.count() Cheers.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have added the `PHP` code snippet. I do the counting outside of `mongoDB`. As you can see, it is quite a straightforward query.

Comment: One thing to note is that the fluctuation usually occurs when one of the documents is updated and crawled (no increase in number of docs, just change in value of a field. `db.collection.save()` is used for `upserting`. The field being changed is not the ones used in the condition for query.

Comment: Hi, Do you use mongo replicas (primary/secondary) in your setup ? Could it be that your query hit an out-of-date slave. You then see a stable count number due to the eventual-consistent nature ?

Comment: Does that come out of the box? I didn't consciously do such a setup. But thanks for the tip, I will check if it is indeed this issue.

Comment: No it doesnt come out of the box, you have to set it up. What version of mongodb are you running ? Have a read through the concurrency (locks) page http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/administration/production-notes/#mmapv1 (mmapv1 is the default). hopefully it can provides more hints.

Comment: Thanks again for the many tips. perhaps you can compile them into one answer and I can accept the answer if the direction was indeed correct.